# Removing a .jpg extension from a string in php

Tags: php

I have the following code for a gallery. When the thumbnail is clicked, I would like to open the big image in another window (which it does) and then be able to navigate to the next image in the new window, but in order to do this, I need to strip the .jpg off the filenames so that I can just '+1' to the filename, as they are sequentially numbered.

For example, files are numbered 001.jpg, 002.jpg, 003.jpg etc.

I currently have:

```
    echo '<p>basename=' . basename($i) . '</p>';
```

Which give the name of the file with .jpg extension, for example `basename=001.jpg`.

Then I have :

```
    $image = basename($i); // to give the variable $image
    $img = str_replace('.jpg',$image, ''); //to take off the .jpg extension
```

but the output I expect, 001, doesn't echo. It just has nothing... `img=`

```
    echo '<p>img=' . $img . '</p>';
```

What am I doing wrong? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Many thanks, Kirsty

Comment: You mean `str_replace('.jpg',$image, '')`?

Comment: I don't know... Do I? That's why I'm asking... I'm trying to learn this as I'm going along... I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$YourPicture = 'cat.jpg';
$without_extension = pathinfo($YourPicture, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

result will be

```
cat
```

Comment: You Most Welcome :)